# My Extension Method Does Not Work

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

I am building a Unit Conversion Library and am having a strange issue with an extension method:

I am attempting to add an Extension Method to this Interface:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public interface DistanceType
    {
        double ConversionFactorToStandardUnit { get; }
    }
}
```

In another class, I have this extension method:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1.DistanceTypes.Imperial.Inch
{
    public static class DistanceTypeExtension
    {
        public static Inch Inch(this DistanceType passedDistance)
        {
            return new Inch();
        }
    }
}
```

but when I attempt to use it:

```
using ClassLibrary1.DistanceTypes.Imperial;
using ClassLibrary1.DistanceTypes.Imperial.Inch;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ImperialTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ExtensionTest()
        {
            Distance d = new Distance(5, DistanceType.Inch());

            Assert.AreEqual(5, d.ToDoubleAsInches());
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error saying DistanceType does not contatin a definition for Inch

Comment: extension method is called via instance of Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension Method is called via instance of Type, what I see you are calling it on `Type` directly:

```
DistanceType distanceType = new DistanceType();
Distance d = new Distance(5, distanceType.Inch());
```

and you also need to a create a class that implements `DistanceType`

Comment: `DistanceType` is an interface so the OP needs to new a class that implements it.

Comment: Yes that is also needed but currently OP is calling it wrong way

Comment: But they still cannot do `new DistanceType()` since that is an interface.

Comment: @juharr agreed I just explained that how extension method is called

Answer (score 1):

First off you need something that implements that interface.

```
public class ImplementsDistanceType : DistanceType ...
```

Then you can create an instance of that and call the extension method on it.

```
var d = new ImplementsDistanceType();
var i = d.Inch();
```

Also you might want to use the standard naming convention for interfaces that puts an `I` before the name like.

```
public interface IDistanceType ...
```

Comment: This answer provides a little more explanation to the point that Ehsan was trying to make. And while the point on naming of the interface is an opinion, it's a strongly supported and accepted naming convention that I happen to agree with.